# Async autoreleasepool

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, async-await, swift-concurrency

I have a situation where I'm creating many Cocoa objects in a loop using `async/await`, and the memory spikes because the objects are only released when the loop is over (instead of every iteration).

The solution would be to use an `autoreleasepool`. However, I can't seem to get `autoreleasepool` to work with `async/await`.

Here is an example:

```
func getImage() async -> NSImage? {
    return NSImage(named: "imagename") // Do some work
}

Task {
    // This leaks
    for _ in 0 ..< 1000000 {
        let image = await getImage()
        print(image!.backgroundColor)
    }
}
```

The memory spikes all the way up to 220MB, which is a bit too much for me.

Normally, you could wrap the inner loop in a `autoreleasepool`, and it would fix the problem, but when I try it with an `async` function, I get this error:

```
Cannot pass function of type '() async -> ()' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
```

Is there any way around this? Or is there another method to accomplish the same goal of releasing the Cocoa objects inside of the loop?

Comment: Nevertheless that is not a "leak". The memory is _used_ during the loop but it is released when it's all over, correct?

Comment: @matt Yes, you're right. My bad. However the memory spikes a lot inside the loop

Comment: Dispatch queues and NSThreads manage their own autorelease pool. So, _maybe_  **Task** does the same? If it does, just wrap your inner async function into a Task. I didn't check this myself, though. But it would be very interesting to know! ;)

Comment: You should post about this on the Swift forums. https://forums.swift.org/ I haven't seen any discussion about how auto-release pools and actors interact. It might have been an overlooked detail. Worth bringing it up!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the difficulty. `autoreleasepool` compiles and works for me just fine inside an `async` method.

Comment: @matt the issue is trying to call an async method inside the autoreleasepool block

Answer (score 9):

@CouchDeveloper mentioned to wrap `getImage` in a `Task`, as it has its own `autoreleasepool`, and it seems to work!

Just change

```
func getImage() async -> NSImage? {
    return NSImage(named: "imagename") // Do some work
}
```

to

```
func getImage() async -> NSImage? {
    await Task {
        return NSImage(named: "imagename") // Do some work
    }.value
}
```